# Javascript in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I cant seem to get the following code to work;

```
function add_js_functions(){

$gpls_woo_rfq_cart = 
gpls_woo_rfq_get_item(gpls_woo_rfq_cart_tran_key() . '_' . 'gpls_woo_rfq_cart');

if(is_array($gpls_woo_rfq_cart)){
$count = count($gpls_woo_rfq_cart);    
}else{
$count = 0;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var getQuoteIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-account");

if(1 != 0) {
    getQuoteIcon[0].style.display = "none";
   }

</script>
<?php }
add_action('init','add_js_functions');
```

The php above the script stores a variable from the quote form on the number of items in the form.

I tried the javascript by itself and its seemed to work but its not working in the functions file.

At the moment im using (1 != 0) to make sure its true and to hide the item so I know the JS works, what will happen afterwards is this will become;

```
if (<?php $count != 0 ?>) {
//rest of the JS here
}
```

So that when the page loads, if the form is empty of items then this icon will be hidden (it starts off as inline-block and i dont know how to change this).

Comment: You might be loading the script before the element is actually available. Test by doing `console.log( getQuoteIcon)` right after  you assign that varialbe. Also, you can try changing `init` to `wp_footer`.

Comment: This worked disinfor, if you post this as an answer i can mark it correct.

Comment: Posted as an answer! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are loading the JS too soon and the element you are targeting isn't available yet.

Use `add_action('wp_footer')` to load the JS in the footer.

```
function add_js_functions(){

$gpls_woo_rfq_cart = 
gpls_woo_rfq_get_item(gpls_woo_rfq_cart_tran_key() . '_' . 'gpls_woo_rfq_cart');

if(is_array($gpls_woo_rfq_cart)){
$count = count($gpls_woo_rfq_cart);    
}else{
$count = 0;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var getQuoteIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-account");

if(1 != 0) {
    getQuoteIcon[0].style.display = "none";
   }

</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer','add_js_functions');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want your php to be `<?php echo $count != 0 ?>`.

Your PHP is executed server-side, and Javascript client side, the two don't communicate by passing variables between the two. In order to get your PHP variable into your Javascript, you need to `echo` it.

Comment: OP posted that will be future code. The testing scenario of `if ( 1 != 0 )` is not working - even though it should be. `$count` doesn't need to be echoed in this case, since it's a check to see if the JS will even get loaded.

Comment: I did forget to write echo in my original post, that was the intention though.